# What does [] mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

In the following javascript code there is `[]` being assigned as the value of a variable, what does it mean?

```
var openTollDebug = [];
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

it is an array literal. It is not quite the same as declaring `new Array()` - the Array object can be overwritten in JavaScript, but the array literal can't. Here's an example to demonstrate

```
// let's overwrite the Array object
Array = function(id) {
 this.id = id;
}

var a = new Array(1);
var b = [];

console.log(a.hasOwnProperty("id")); // true
console.log(b.hasOwnProperty("id")); // false

console.log(a.push); // false, push doesn't exist on a
console.log(b.push); // true,  but it does on b

b.push(2);
console.log(b); // outputs [2]
```

Comment: So long as `Array` hasn't been overwritten, `new Array()` and `[]` are functionally identical.

Comment: @Tim - yes they are. There is also a difference in intializing values and length - `new Array(5)` is not the same as `[5]` :)

Comment: for the person who gave the -1 : why? I believe I qualified that declaring `[]` and `new Array()` is not quite the same as the latter is based on the condition that `Array` has not been overwritten.

Comment: @RussCam, So how do we override `[]` constructor?

Answer (score 7):

It means an array.

```
var openTollDebug = [];
```

declares the `openTollDebug` variable and initializes it to an empty array. To put elements into the array you could do the following:

```
var stringArray = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3'];
alert(stringArray[1]); // displays 'element2'
var numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
alert(numberArray[2]); // displays 3
var objectArray = [{ name: 'john' }, { name: 'peter' }, { name: 'tom' }];
alert(objectArray[1].name); // displays 'peter'
```

Answer (score 6):

It's an empty array, and is equal to

```
var openTollDebug = new Array();
```

Answer (score 4):

It is shorthand for empty array. Same as new Array(). 
Also {} is an empty object. Objects are like hashtables in Js so you can use it as a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

It creates an empty array.
This is a good way to have a non-null object.
In JavaScript, it is then very easy to add functions and properties to that object. For example:

```
openTollDebug.title = 'hello world';
openTollDebug.show = function(){alert('Debug');};
```

As an array, you can add items:

```
openTollDebug.push('added item');
openTollDebug[3] = 'just add anywhere';
```

Answer (score 1):

Many languages have constructs for literals. The [] is an Array literal.

```
var openTollDebug = [];
```

is the same as

```
var openTollDebug = new Array();
```

Just know that using [] preferred for performance reasons.

There are other literals like Object literals

```
var MyObject = {
              name:'default',
              age:22,
              hobbies:["golf","video games","otherstuff"]
}
```

Notice the array literal with data. The [] creates an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use literals due to performance. You dont write

```
var obj = new Object({name: 'John'})
```

You just write

```
var obj = {name: 'John'}
```

You also dont write

```
button.onclick = new Function("alert('Clicked!')");
```

You write

```
button.onclick = function () { alert('Clicked') }
```

And here's [a link](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/) to a nice blog post about it

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = [] //it is an array literal.
```

Comment: You should check to see if there are answers which already provide the same information.