# Javascript array best practice to use [] instead of new array?

Tags: javascript

I read at many tutorials that the current best practices to create a new javascript array is to use

```
var arr = []
```

instead of

```
var arr = new Array()
```

What's the reasoning behind that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might be because the Array object can be overwritten in JavaScript but the array literal notation cannot. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280285/what-does-mean-in-javascript/2280295#2280295) for an example

Comment: This depends per implementation though. At least in the past [] used the Array constructor in some JS engines (iirc there was a fuzz about scripts being able to capture array creation for JSONP requests by overriding the array constructor).

Comment: @reko_t - that's very true. I know in Firefox the array literal doesn't use the Array constructor, not sure of the others (no way to check at the moment, could someone confirm?)

Comment: Would someone be able to fix the link please? iPhone editing is tricky :)

Comment: Already did it 2 mins ago, Sean did it once again the minute thereafter.

Answer (score 12):

Also note that doing:

```
var x = [5];
```

Is different than doing:

```
var x = new Array(5);
```

The former creates an initializes an array with one element with value of 5. The later creates an initializes an array with 5 undefined elements.

Comment: And, to make it funnier, `new Array(1, 2)` equals `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 3):

It's less typing, which in my book always wins :-)

Once I fixed a weird bug on one of our pages. The page wanted to create a list of numeric database keys as a Javascript array.  The keys were always large integers (a high bit was always set as an indicator).  The original code looked like:

```
 var ids = new Array(${the.list});
```

Well, guess what happened when the list had only one value in it?

```
 var ids = new Array(200010123);
```

which means, "create an array and initialize it so that there are 200 million empty entries".

Comment: oh well whatever - I can't recall exactly what the IDs looked like, but it was big enough to cause an immediate out-of-memory

Answer (score 1):

Usually an array literal(var a=[1,2,3] or a=[]) is the way to go.

But once in a while you need an array where the length itself is the defining feature of the array.

var A=Array(n) would (using a literal) need two expressions-

var A=[]; A.length=n;

In any event, you do not need the 'new' operator with the Array constructor,
not in the way that you DO need 'new' with a new Date object, say.

Answer (score 1):

To create Array without Length

```
var arr = [];
```

To create Array with Length more dynamically

```
var arr;
( arr = [] ).length = 10;  // 10 is array length
```

To create Array with Length less dynamically

```
var arr = [];
arr.length = 10;
```