# Javascript Array constructor issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I'm wondering about why isn't advisable to use array declaration by:

```
 var arr = new Array()
```

as I thought declaring by `[]` was supposed to be protected in case of overwrite `Array` but...

```
Array = 1;
var arr = [] // boom  
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

Personally, I prefer using `var arr = []`,
but now I don't know what is the advantage of using `[]` instead of `Array` except that write faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> as I thought declaring by `[]` was supposed to be protected in case of overwrite `Array` but...

It is under EcmaScript 5 but not under EcmaScript 3, so it won't be on older browsers.

The relevant portion of the spec is http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.4

> 1. Let array be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression `new Array()` where `Array` is the **standard built-in constructor with that name**.

The bolded text was added in EcmaScript 5 but was not present in EcmaScript 3.

Answer (score 4):

Both methods are interchangeable (regarding functionailty), except for one case:

These are **not equivalent**:

```
var array = new Array(3);  // <-- Creates an array with length 3
var array = [3];

//If you wanted to use the `Array` to create an array with one element, use:
var array = new Array();
array[0] = 3;
```

`[]` is not only shorter, but also consistent. The `Array` constructor is only useful for creating arrays with an initial length.

Comment: Note `[]` is favoured because 1) it minimizes better and 2) `new Array()` has a functional call overhead where as `[]` can be optimized better internally in javascript engines.

Answer (score 2):

There's already lots of similar posts on SO.

**See this:**

[Javascript array best practice to use [] instead of new array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944380/javascript-array-best-practice-to-use-instead-of-new-array)

**And this:**

[Use of JavaScript new Array(n) Declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246408/use-of-javascript-array-new-arrayn-declaration)

Comment: Instead of posting this as an answer, you can flag the answer for attention, and say "Duplicate of: <other question(s) here>". When you get the privilege to add comments, this would also be suitable for a comment.

Comment: Will do - Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it doesn't really matter you use `new Array()` or `=[]`. Because, most of today's browsers' Javascript engines are smart enough to take advantages of small implementation differences. I frequently use `=[]` just because of shave off some extra bytes from the javascript source.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a [test](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/56150009/jstests/array-literal.html). It appears that if you override window.Array with anything except another function it won't work.

Answer (score -5):

[] it doesn't mean anything in fact Javascript doesn't explicitly mention anything like that.
so you have to follow the variable declaration rules as its standard mentions.

Comment: don't waste your time with this I suggest you move up and learn rest of concepts of Javascript .

Comment: It still doesn't address the question, though; maybe expand on what you're trying to say a little.

Comment: I just show the direction and you have to travel by yourself.

Comment: I am not here for those tiny pixelated badges and reputations. 
perhaps people like you can have some fun thumbing down on me but I don't care.

Comment: @Gryphes I did not *vote down*, because `-3` is enough to fade an answer. I encourage wrong answers to be deleted, so that SO remains clean.