# Declaring an empty array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to declare an empty array and was just wondering if there are any fundamental differences between these two ways of declaring an empty array.

Can someone please explain the difference between these two:

```
var myArray = [];
```

and

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944380/javascript-array-best-practice-to-use-instead-of-new-array