# Array problems with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Jquery code that is following:

```
var selectedQuestions = $("#SelectedQuestions");
var selectedCustomQuestions = $("#SelectedCustomQuestions");
var currentIds = new Array();
var currentText = new Array();

$("#CustomPickedTable td[data-question-id]").each(function () {
    var clickedId = $(this).attr("data-question-id");
    currentIds.push(clickedId);

    $('#CustomPickedTable tr').each(function () {
        var ClickedText= $(this).find("td[data-attr-id]:first").html();
        currentText.push(ClickedText);
    });
});

selectedCustomQuestions.val(currentText.join("|"));
selectedQuestions.val(currentIds.join(","));

$("form").submit();
}
```

I have two types of TD in my table that is following:

```
<td data-question-id="7">test</td>
```

and

```
<td data-attr-id="5">test</td>
```

I want to be able to sort em into different hiddenfields these are my hiddenfields:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedCustomQuestions, new { @id = "SelectedCustomQuestions" }) 
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedQuestions, new { @id = "SelectedQuestions" })
```

my Jquery code  works when it comes to fill my array with CurrentIds but with currentText I get problems, if I have two  `<td data-attr-id="5">test</td>` in my table they get duplicated in my array list and my array lenght is 7-10 which is weird. The CurrentText should only have 2 length and its not. How can I fix this?

Example on the problem.

I have this following inside my table:

```
<td data-attr-id="5">aaaa</td>
<td data-attr-id="5">ddd</td>
<td data-question-id="5">test</td>
<td data-question-id="15">test</td>
```

and this is what happens when i debug my jquery code

[image: example]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this one with slight modification.

```
var selectedQuestions = $("#SelectedQuestions");
    var selectedCustomQuestions = $("#SelectedCustomQuestions");
    var currentIds = new Array();
    var currentText = new Array();

    $("#CustomPickedTable td[data-question-id]").each(function () {
        var clickedId = $(this).attr("data-question-id");
        currentIds.push(clickedId);
    });
    $('#CustomPickedTable td[data-attr-id]').each(function () {
        var ClickedText = $(this).html();
        currentText.push(ClickedText);
    });

    selectedCustomQuestions.val(currentText.join("|"));
    selectedQuestions.val(currentIds.join(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using "td[data-attr-id]:first" in your find selector, but you are "using data-attri-id" in your html, notice the added i.

edit :
You might also wanna use

```
var currentIds = [];
var currentText = [];
```

instead of :

```
var currentIds = new Array();
var currentText = new Array();
```

see:
[What does [] mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280285/what-does-mean-in-javascript/2280295#2280295)