# What are the best practices to follow when declaring an array in Javascript? 

Tags: javascript

When I need to declare a new array I use this notation

```
var arr = new Array();
```

But when testing online, for example on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/#javascript,html), a warning signals me to "Use the array literal notation []."

I didn't find a reason to avoid using the constructor. Is in some way less efficient than using `[]`? Or is it bad practice?

Is there a good reason to use `var arr = [];` instead of `var arr = new Array();`?

Comment: Both are fine. You just save some bytes in transmission.

Comment: There are indeed differences. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2280285/921204

Comment: Note: there are differences *if Array has been overwritten* only.

Comment: @apkd on some browsers there's a significant performance difference

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't see that on the linked question.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

*Mostly*, people use `var a = []` because [Douglas Crockford says so](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/).

His reasons include the non-intuitive and inconsistent behaviour of `new Array()`:

```
var a = new Array(5);     // an array pre-sized to 5 elements long
var b = new Array(5, 10); // an array with two elements in it
```

Note that there's no way with `new Array()` to create an array with just *one* pre-specified number element in it!

Using `[]` is actually more efficient, [and safer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280285/what-does-mean-in-javascript)!  It's possible to overwrite the `Array` constructor and make it do odd things, but you can't overwrite the behaviour of `[]`.

Personally, I always use the `[]` syntax, and similarly always use `{}` syntax in place of `new Object()`.

Comment: "you can't overwrite the behaviour of []." Are you sure about this? I thought that you could overwrite the Array constructor to affect [], and the Object constructor to affect {}, at least on some implementations.

Comment: @Random832 maybe in older browsers, but not in ES5 compatible implementations, where the spec says that `[]` calls an internal constructor, not whatever value `Array.constructor` happens to have at the time.

Comment: **Bonus:** Array literals are much faster than creating new arrays using the `Array` constructor: http://jsperf.com/new-array

Comment: @MathiasBynens only sometimes.

Comment: Ew @ the [] working differently because of the internal constructor thing. The inconsistency will cause more confusion than it saves. Edit: Ah, security concern. I get it.

Answer (score 48):

One significant difference is that `[]` will *always* instantiate a new Array, whereas `new Array` could be [hijacked to create a different object](http://jsfiddle.net/ASvqT/).

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var foo,
        bar;
    //don't do this, it's a bad idea
    function Array() {
        alert('foo');
    }
    foo = new Array();
    bar = [];
}());​
```

In my example code, I've kept the `Array` function hidden from the rest of the document scope, however it's more likely that if you ever run into this sort of issue that the code won't have been left in a nice closure, and will likely be difficult to locate.

<sub>**Disclaimer**: It's not a good idea to hijack the `Array` constructor.</sub>

Comment: IIRC, in older browsers overriding the Array constructor would also cause literals to be interpreted incorrectly. There was a GMail CSRF [vulnerability](http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com.br/2006/01/advanced-web-attack-techniques-using.html) a while ago the involved overriding the array constructor and new browsers ignore overloading for literals for this precise reason.

Comment: Counter-disclaimer: it has however been exceedingly helpful and useful to enhance the Array constructor over the years.

Answer (score 26):

## for maintainability, use `[]`

The array literal is more predictable, as most developers use it. Most array usage out there will be using the literal, and there is value in having your code match up with what other developers use.

## for empty arrays, use `[]`

```js
var ns = [];
var names = [ 'john', 'brian' ];
```

As shown [here](http://jsperf.com/array-constructor-versus-literal), using the literal for empty and a couple of known elements is fatster than the Array constructor.

## for an array of known size, use `new Array(size)`

If the size is known, then using the Array constructor significantly improves performance. However it also means you have to deal with an array which already has 'undefined' filling 
all it's values.

As shown [here](http://jsperf.com/array-filling-speed/)

```js
// fill an array with 100 numbers
var ns = new Array( 100 );
for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    ns[i] = i;
}
```

This also works for [very small arrays too](http://jsperf.com/array-filling-speed/2).

Answer (score 12):

No, there is actually no reason to use one notation over the other one for empty Arrays.

However, most browsers show a slightly better performance using `x = [];` than calling the *Constructor*.

If you need to create an Array with a specific size, you kind of *need* to use `x = new Array(10);` for instance, which would create an Array with 10 `undefined` slots.

Comment: @Alnitak: which you already mentioned, is not very intuitive and concise.

Comment: I put together a jsperf to compare performance: http://jsperf.com/array-constructor-versus-literal. At least for me on Chrome 20 on Ubuntu, the literal is twice as fast as the constructor.

Comment: @jAndy, [I can think of one difference for empty arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500492/what-are-the-best-practices-to-follow-when-declaring-an-array-in-javascript/11506130#11506130).

Comment: jAndy, why would you want an array with "10 empty slots" in JavaScript?

In reality, you can do the exact same thing with:

    var arr = [];  arr[9] = "omega";

 1. Arrays in JS are totally dynamic, you can reference any index you would like, and it will just be "undefined".
This is just as true as if you were to say:
    var arr = new Array(10); arr[23];

 2. the array's length is going to be set to the highest value that has anything in it, regardless of how many undefined slots are in between.

Or you can set it, yourself.

[] might not cure cancer, but it marginally-better.

Answer (score 7):

- var arr=[] uses the array/object literal
- var arr = new Array() use the array/object constructor

The speediest way to define an array or object is literal way, because you don't need to call the constructor

```
var arr1 = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4);
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

alert(arr1[0]); // 1
alert(arr2[0]); // 1

var arr3 = new Array(200);
var arr4 = [200];

alert(arr3[0]); // 'undefined'
alert(arr4[0]); // 200
```

Comment: For reference, behind the scenes, `var arr = [];` logically uses a constructor too.  It's just *always* the built-in array constructor, rather than whatever function is currently going by the name `Array`.

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct only. But most of the people use `var a = []`

Three Ways to Declare an Array in JavaScript.

**method 1**: We can explicitly declare an array with the JavaScript "new" keyword to instantiate the array in memory (i.e. create it, and make it available).

```
// Declare an array (using the array constructor)
var arlene1 = new Array();
var arlene2 = new Array("First element", "Second", "Last");
```

**method 2**: we use an alternate method to declaring arrays.

```
// Declare an array (using literal notation)
var arlene1 = [];
var arlene2 = ["First element", "Second", "Last"];
```

**method 3**: JavaScript also lets you create arrays indirectly, by calling specific methods.

```
// Create an array from a method's return value
var carter = "I-learn-JavaScript";
var arlene3 = carter.split("-");
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a limit the constructor can take as arguments.

On most systems I encoutered the limit is 2^16 (2 bytes):

```
var myFreshArr = new Array(0,1,2,3 ..... 65536);
```

That will cause an error (too many arguments....)

When using the literal [] you don't have such problems.

In case you don't care about such big arrays, I think you can use whatever you prefer.

Comment: Can you cite an example of where a person might reasonably want to create an array pre-populated with 70,000 values? Though, it does really explain some of the awful websites I've seen that never seem to finish loading...

Comment: John O, I've seen some SCARY JSON implementations in my time, involving arrays of 2D/3D arrays, featuring IATA(airport) codes, airline-companies, tour-operators, resorts, et cetera...
...all stuffed into one array.

It's...  ...1MB+ JSON downloads make me want to cry.

Answer (score 4):

```
var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4];
```

is sugar

```
var array = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

is salt

Comment: and where to use it, for coffee or for pasta ?

Answer (score 3):

It's because `new Array()` is ambiguous. These are the correct constructors:

```
// Using brackets
[element0, element1, ..., elementN]

// Using new AND a list of elements
new Array(element0, element1, ..., elementN)

// Using new AND an integer specifying the array length
new Array(arrayLength)
```