# How to create a comma seperated values by reading JSON using node js

Tags: node.js

I have a JSON as follows:

```
{
    "workloadId": "68cf9344-5a3c-4e4a-927c-c1c9b6e48ccc",
    "elements": [
        {
            "name": "element1",
            "uri": "vm/hpcloud/nova/large"
        },
        {
            "name": "element2",
            "uri": "vm/hpcloud/nova/small"
        }
    ],
    "workloadStatus": "none"
}
```

I need to get the comma seperated string as follows :
element1,element2

when i tried as given below , i got empty string:

```
app.post('/pricingdetails', function(req, res) {

    var workload = req.body;

    var arr = new Array();
    for(var index in workload.elements)
    {
        arr[index] = workload.elements[index].uri;
    }
    console.log(arr.join(","));
}
```

Comment: You could console.log arr[index] after each row in the loop. it doesn't seem wrong at first glance, except that perhaps workload is not a json object, but a string itself?

Comment: Assigning the JSON listed above directly to workload works as expected.  Looks like the error may be in the assignment.  Instead of workload = req.body, try assigning the response to workload.

Answer (score 1):

Elements is an array. Never use for/in for arrays. Use a standard for loop instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < workload.elements.length; ++i) {
    arr.push(workload.elements[i].uri);
}
console.log(arr.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Node will let you use the `forEach` method instead of a `for` loop or the `for/in` (the latter of which has the potential to [cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/243778/1750305)). 
Avoiding `new Array()` is [another Crockford-ism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11500550/1750305), but I also just find the `[]` notation more concise and readable.

```
var workload = req.body;

var arr = [];

workload.elements.forEach(function(el) {
    arr.push(el.uri);
});

console.log(arr.join(','));
```

These sort of nitpicks aside, like dc5 I tried just defining a variable with your JSON and your code did what I would expect (returning the array elements joined by a comma). What are you using to call that route, and how are you passing it the indicated JSON?

EDIT: using

```
curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"workloadId": "68cf9344-5a3c-4e4a-927c-c1c9b6e48ccc", "elements": [{"name": "element1", "uri": "vm/hpcloud/nova/large"}, {"name": "element2", "uri": "vm/hpcloud/nova/small"} ], "workloadStatus": "none"}'  http://localhost:3000/pricingdetails
```

fails for me if [bodyParser()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser) isn't used. With `app.use(express.bodyParser());` in my code, it works as expected.