# Canvas/JavaScript - flip color of a square on mouse click

Tags: javascript, canvas

Below is the code to create a 6x6 grid that is randomly populated with white/black squares. At the moment when you click on a square, in console it displays the position of within an array of a given square. What I am struggling with is to make it flip the color once you click on a square (eg. when you click on a white square, it becomes black, etc.). The change should also update the array as in the end I will be checking whether the resulting patter has a line of symmetry.

```
// Create canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasCreate = function(w, h) {
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
};

function resetCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawGrid(genArray(6));

}

// Generate a 6x6 array of 0s or 1s
function genArray(aSize) {
    a = new Array();
    for (var i=0;i<aSize;i++) {
        a[i] = new Array();
        for (var j=0;j<aSize;j++) {
            a[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        }
    }
    return a
}

function drawGrid(arr) {
    var n = 6;
    for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for (var j=0;j<n;j++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#555';
            if (arr[i][j] === 1) {
                ctx.fillRect(i*50, j*50, 50, 50);
            }
            ctx.rect(i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    // Get mouse position within canvas
    function mouseClick(e) {
        var mouseX, mouseY;

        if(e.offsetX) {
            mouseX = e.offsetX;
            mouseY = e.offsetY;
        }
        else if(e.layerX) {
            mouseX = e.layerX;
            mouseY = e.layerY;
        }
        var gridX = Math.floor(mouseX / 50);
        var gridY = Math.floor(mouseY / 50);
        console.log(gridX, gridY);

        var xy = arr[gridX][gridY];
        if (xy == 0) {
            xy = 1;
            console.log("white");
        }
        else if (xy == 1) {
            xy = 0;
            console.log("black");
        }
        //
    }
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseClick, false);
};



arr = genArray(6);
canvasCreate(300, 300);
drawGrid(arr);
```

... and corresponding html:

```
<button onclick="resetCanvas()">Reset</button>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Edit: to show what I've tried:

```
var xy = arr[gridX][gridY];
        if (xy == 0) {
            xy = 1;
            console.log("white");
            drawGrid(arr);
        }
        else if (xy == 1) {
            xy = 0;
            console.log("black");
            drawGrid(arr);
        }
```

As you can see above, the position in the array is identified (eg. (0, 3)), then the value gets changed between 0 and 1 and the whole grid should get redrawn. It changes the colors of some squares, but not in a way I intended. Additionally (after a few clicks, it seems to choke a browser indicating that I'm doing something wrong.

Edit 2: Upon the comment below I've updated it to:

```
var xy = arr[gridX][gridY];
        if (xy == 0) {
            arr[gridX][gridY] = 1;
            console.log("white");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            drawGrid(arr);
        }
        else if (xy == 1) {
            arr[gridX][gridY] = 0;
            console.log("black");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            drawGrid(arr);
        }
```

Still it malfunctions and gets the browser not responsive.

Comment: Can you show us some code you've tried ?

Comment: See above. I've added it

Comment: You have to update the array itself `arr[gridX][gridY]` instead of using `xy` which is not a reference to the array, but the same value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's true. I've changed it. I also added a line to clear canvas before drawing it but it still works not as intended. Usually after one click the browser seem to choke/slow down.

Comment: Be carefull with your iterators (`i` and `j`) you made them global, also, each time you call `drawGrid` you add a listener to the canvas

Comment: Got it. Thank you - will update the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you will find working bit of code, but let me first go over everything that I changed:

1. You had to many variables without `var` - it wasn't the source of the problem here but try to always use `var` (P.S I didn't go over all methods so check again)
2. Removed use of `new Array()` - again wasn't the problem here but try to always use `[]`
3. Relevant to the problem - moved `mouseClick` out of `drawGrid` and the `addEventListener` so it is not called needlessly with every mouseclick
4. Relevant to the problem - `resetCanvas` did not really reset anything since you forgot to save the new generated array in the `arr` variable.
5. Saved the 1, 0 in `arr` not in `xy`
6. Last but not least - `drawGrid` was only drawing black - added drawing white two. And added fun colors as example. Without this change white was flipping to black. But black wasn't flipping to white.

   ```
   var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

   var canvasCreate = function(w, h) {
     canvas.width = w;
     canvas.height = h;
   };

   function resetCanvas() {
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     arr = genArray(6);
     drawGrid(arr);
   }

   // Generate a 6x6 array of 0s or 1s
   function genArray(aSize) {
     var a = [];
     for (i=0;i<aSize;i++) {
       a[i] = [];
       for (j=0;j<aSize;j++) {
         a[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
       }
     }
     return a;
   }

   function drawGrid(arr) {
     var n = 6;
     for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
       for (var j=0;j<n;j++) {
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.strokeStyle = '#555';
         if (arr[i][j] === 1) {
           ctx.fillStyle = '#faf';
           ctx.fillRect(i*50, j*50, 50, 50);
         } else {
           ctx.fillStyle = '#ffa';
           ctx.fillRect(i*50, j*50, 50, 50);
         }
         ctx.rect(i*50, j*50, 50, 50);
         ctx.stroke();
       }
     }
   };

   var arr = genArray(6);
   canvasCreate(300, 300);
   drawGrid(arr);

   // Get mouse position within canvas
   function mouseClick(e) {
     var mouseX, mouseY;

     if(e.offsetX) {
       mouseX = e.offsetX;
       mouseY = e.offsetY;
     }
     else if(e.layerX) {
       mouseX = e.layerX;
       mouseY = e.layerY;
     }
     var gridX = Math.floor(mouseX / 50);
     var gridY = Math.floor(mouseY / 50);
     console.log(gridX, gridY);

     var xy = arr[gridX][gridY];
     if (xy == 0) {
       arr[gridX][gridY] = 1;
       console.log("white");
     }
     else if (xy == 1) {
       arr[gridX][gridY] = 0;
       console.log("black");
     }

     drawGrid(arr);
   }

   canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseClick, false);
   ```

Comment: Thank you. Works great. Love the colors:). Point number 2 - why is that so?

Comment: I think the main argument behind number 2 is that Array constructor is not very intuitive to use - that is how it changes it's behaviour depending on the arguments. So to avoid all this confusion and possible mistakes most agree not to use it. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500492/what-are-the-best-practices-to-follow-when-declaring-an-array-in-javascript