# Delete multiple items using checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm making a shopping list, I've already have a function to delete a single item, as of right now, I'm having a problem to delete multiple items using checkbox. My item table is consist of itemName, itemId, and listId

I'm using ajax jquery

Delete Multiple JS function

```
function deleteMultiple(){
            $("#deleteMultiple").click(function(){
                var itemsDelete = new Array();
                $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                    itemsDelete.push( $(this).val() );
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "deleteMultiple.php",
                    data: { itemsDelete : itemsDelete },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(){
                    }
                });
                return false;

            });
        }
        }
```

PHP function to spit out all the items in a specific list

```
$sql = ("SELECT listId FROM list WHERE listName = '$listName' LIMIT 1");
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $_SESSION['listIdIn'] = $row['listId'];
}

$sql = "(SELECT itemName FROM item WHERE listId =". $_SESSION['listIdIn'] .")";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<li><input name = 'checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value ='" . $row["itemName"]. "'>" . $row["itemName"]. "</input><input type='button' class='deleteItem' Value='Delete'/></li>";
    }
} else {
    return null;
}
```

and the PHP function to delete multiple item

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM item";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $itemsDelete = $_REQUEST['itemsDelete'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM 'item' WHERE itemName = '$itemsDelete'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
```

Thank you

**UPDATE:**So I changed my deleteMultiple.php, here's how the code looks now

```
$itemsDelete = $_REQUEST['itemsDelete'];
var_dump ($itemsDelete);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($itemsDelete); $i++){
    $itemsDeleteName = $itemsDelete[$i];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM 'item' WHERE 'itemName' IN (//I read from some article I have to use implode, I tried but it's not working) AND 'listId' = ".$_SESSION['listIdIn'];
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
```

The var_dump gives out this result

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "item3" [1]=> string(5) "item4" [2]=> string(9) "iteeeemmm" }
```

So far, by clicking the delete button, I can pass the values into multipleDelete.php, I can pass the value into php array, the problem right now, I cannot use the value in the php array and delete MySQL database

Comment: So what is the issue, exactly? Have you `var_dump`ed the variable where the ajax posts? (`deleteMultiple.php`)? Is it posting the variables?

Comment: You have quite a few errors here and quite a few unknowns.

Comment: it seems I cannot pass my javascript array into php script

Comment: Are you still trying to solve this problem?\

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer one part of the issue which is clear.  **Please note** that you may have other problems, and this is one of them for certain.  In order to help you, however, you *will have to post more information*.  Narrow down the problem, use `var_dump`, your browser console, etc.

In your jQuery, you are not properly setting / pushing on the right variable.  Change this portion:

```
 // Here you declare the variable itemsDelete.  This is fine.
 var itemsDelete = new Array();       
 // Note it's preferable to declare the variable like so:    
 // var itemsDelete = [];

 $("input:checked").each(function() {
     // Here you are pushing onto an array called data.  You didn't declare that, so replace it...
     // data['itemsDelete[]'].push($(this).val());
     itemsDelete.push( $(this).val() );
  });
```

Your AJAX appears to be OK.

Your PHP has some typos / issues in it (in some places you use `mysqli_`, in others you use `mysql_`.

Good luck.

(Note: for why to use array literal notation when declaring arrays, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11500550/870729))

Comment: The other part is they're using the wrong identifier qualifiers in `DELETE FROM 'item'`. But they're not checking for errors on the query.

Comment: I've changed according to your suggestion, but again it does not work, I've already updated my question