# javascript How to make the property of superior object to point to an array of inferior objects (a relation)

Tags: javascript

I have made a relation between category and product objects using eval function i.e. this.prodLine = eval(name). It works but how can I substitute an eval() function which is predicated and deemed as tricky?

```
function product( name, price) {
     this.name  = name;
     this.price = price;
 return this;
}
function category( name, description) { 
       this.name = name;
       this.description = description;
       this.prodLine = eval(name); //thanks the eval() we get a list of [objects] product
 return this; 
}
Apps = new Array( new product("Dryer",100),new product("Hairdryer",200),new product("Oven",300));
Cars = new Array( new product("audi",400),new product("bmw",500),new product("citroen",600),new product("dacia",9000) );

categorySet = new Array( 
  new category("Apps","handy home appliances"),
  new category("Cars","tedious four wheelers")
);      
var Produkty = new Array();

var count_prod = categorySet[0].prodLine.length; alert('cat[0] : count_prod='+count_prod);
for (var j = 0; j < count_prod; j++) {
  Produkty[ Produkty.length] = new Array(0,j); 
  alert('KAT[0] count_prod='+count_prod+' : Produkty.length = '+Produkty.length+' j = '+j);
}
var count_prod = categorySet[1].prodLine.length; alert('cat[1] : count_prod='+count_prod);
for (var j = 0; j < count_prod; j++) { 
  Produkty[ Produkty.length] = new Array(1,j); 
  alert('KAT[1] count_prod='+count_prod+' : Produkty.length = '+Produkty.length)+' j = '+j;
}
```

console.table(Produkty);

Comment: Pass the line object alongside the name, i.e. `category("Apps", Apps, "handy home appliances")`?

Comment: Btw, also [avoid `new Array`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11500492/1048572) and use array literals instead, as well as using `Produkty.push(…)` over `Produkty[ Produkty.length] = …`, to make your code more idiomatic

Comment: I don't see any need for `eval()` in this code; you can just pass the arrays into the function directly.