# what is this javascript syntax doing?

Tags: javascript

what actually this syntax doing i am unable to identify in my java script code, could you please help me with this.

```
var bal=Array(2, 1);
```

Comment: Try it out in your console and see what is printed

Comment: What would you expect? For reference, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

This just creates an array with the name of `bal` and two elements: `2` and `1`.

This would be the same as

```
 var bal = [ 2, 1 ];
```

If you pass more than one argument to the `Array` constructor, the arguments will be interpreted as elements of the created array.

On the other hand a single argument specifies the size of the array.

For more information have a look at [the respective MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax).

Answer (score 1):

`var bal=Array(2, 1);` is shorthand for:

```
var bal = new Array(); 
bal[0]=2;       
bal[1]=1;
```

Therefore its creating an array with 2 integer objects, with values `2` & `1`.

Answer (score 1):

It will create a one-dimensional array object of javascript.
So if you want to access the first element of the array i.e.bal[0] will give you 2 and respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This is calling the `Array` function with arguments = [2, 1]. This is essentially equivalent to assigning arguments to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

`Array(2,1)` creates an array with two members, the integers 2 and 1.

It is important to note here that this array declaration syntax provides no way of declaring an array with a single element. That is:

```
Array(5);
```

creates an array of length 5 with undefined members. Use the `[2,1]` syntax instead, because it behaves uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable array which contain the value 2 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_instances):

> A JavaScript array is initialized with the given elements, except in the case where a single argument is passed to the Array constructor and that argument is a number. (See below.) Note that this special case only applies to JavaScript arrays created with the Array constructor, not with array literals created with the bracket syntax.

So your code is equivalent to this:

```
var bal = new Array(); 
bal[0] = 2;
bal[1] = 1;
```

But the [preferred notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280285/what-does-mean-in-javascript/2280295#2280295) is this:

```
var bal = [2, 1];
```