# how to get data from an array within an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array named *derps* and then I make an array inside it:

```
derps[0]=new Array();
```

**how do I get/set data** in the newly created array `derps[0]`?

Comment: Side note: Use `[]` instead of `new Array();`.

Comment: To support jbabey's statement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280285/what-does-mean-in-javascript/2280295#2280295

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
derps[0][0] = 'foo';
derps[0][1] = 'bar';
derps[0].push('foobar');
derps[0] = derps[0].concat([5,6,7]);
// Etc, etc.

console.log(derps[0][1]); // 'bar'
console.log(derps[0][2]); // 'foobar'
console.log(derps[0]);    // ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "foobar", 5, 6, 7]
```

Basically, access `derps[0]` like you'd access any other array, because it *is* an array.
I'm not going to list **[All methods you can use on `derps[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_of_Array_instances)** ;-)

Also, instead of:

```
derps[0] = new Array();
```

You can use the "array literal" notation:

```
derps[0] = []; // Empty array, or:
derps[0] = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']; // <-- With data.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it won't let me select you now but I will later if I remember, this is how I tried it earlier but I must've done something wrong.

Comment: Maybe you made a typo or something, then ;-) Always glad to be of help!

Comment: how would I get the length of derps[0]?

Comment: @user1420493: `derps[0].length`

Comment: Okay, I forgot to update some code so that wasn't working when I was trying it, that's why I asked :P thanks anyways

Comment: wait, it seems to only ever return "1"

Comment: What exactly are you doing?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the array with data already in it:

```
derps[0] = [1, 2, 3];
```

You can assign values to the array:

```
derps[0] = new Array();
derps[0][0] = 1;
derps[0][1] = 2;
derps[0][2] = 3;
```

You can push values to the array:

```
derps[0] = new Array();
derps[0].push(1);
derps[0].push(2);
derps[0].push(3);
```

Comment: Good answer, you covered it all.

Answer (score 0):

You can `push` data into the new array:

```
derps[0].push("some data");
```

As an aside: you may also use an array literal to create `derps[0]`:

```
derps[0] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wish to instantiate the type of the variable before, you can proceed [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/2n68e/3/) (JSFiddle).

```
var derps = [];
derps[0] = [];

derps[0][0] = "test";
derps[0][1] = "test2";

document.write(derps[0][1]);​
```

Don't forget to write `var` if you don't want the variable to be global.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
var derps = [];
derps.push([]);
derps[0].push('foo');
derps[0].push('bar');
```