# Array Object Versus Array Literal - Performance JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Today i was going through some posts in stackoverflow and this reply just popped up. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2280350/548591

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11513602/548591

```
var name = [];
var name = new Array();
```

Is the literal one better in terms of performance than initializing an `new Array Object`.

**Was reading this article now, just wanted to update.**

http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/

Comment: Performance questions should be addressed using performance tools (e.g., http://www.jsperf.com). If you have results and want to know *why* one is better than the other, then that's a different question altogether.

Comment: This answer is pretty exhaustive on this topic: [Why arr = \[\] is faster than arr = new Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-arr-is-faster-than-arr-new-array)

Comment: See also: http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-literal-notation, http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-literal/13, and more generally https://www.google.com/search?q=jsperf+array+literal

Comment: Doesn't [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2280295/1048572) in one of the questions you linked tell enough?

Answer (score 0):

From working on my own direct implementation of ECMA Grammar to make a parser, I can tell you this:

The Array literal `[]` gets parsed directly and then converted into an array object, whereas `new Array()` gets parsed first as a "expression", then checked for the new keyword, then what you want to create (in this case `Array`) and is then evaluated.

I can't tell you exactly how much performance is lost by using `new Array()`, it varies by the Javascript engine. V8 (Chrome) for example, pre-compiles code to optimize it, so it might get converted into a literal `[]` anyway, depending on how it works.

The easiest way would be to make a test function that creates a few hundred thousand arrays and measures the time for the loop with the literal declaration or the constructor initialization respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, according to the tests, initialising `[]` is much faster than using the `new Array`. Besides that, the literal version si much more readable.
And this [has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-arr-is-faster-than-arr-new-array)!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers, **[Literals appear to be up to twice as fast](http://jsperf.com/array-object-array-literal)**. That is, in browsers where there's a significant difference.