# Which way is best to define a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript

I often define an array like this:

```
var arr = new Array();
```

But when my PM saw my code, my PM said that I should define an array like this:

```
var arr = [];
```

and it will be more efficient. I find that there is another defined way `var arr = ();`?

What is the difference between them and which way do you often use?

Comment: What is `var arr = ();` ?

Comment: Best parctice is to use `var arr = [];` instead of `var arr = new Array();` because Array object can be overwritten in JavaScript, but the array literal can't

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe, Array object can be overwritten to what?Can you give me an example?

Comment: this question is already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280285/what-does-mean-in-javascript/2280295#2280295